# how to index each element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to index each element like this 1/8, 2/8, 3/8

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Thumbnail = $('.thm-img'); // main image wrapper

    function ThumbnailCounter() {

        var AllNumber = $(Thumbnail).length;

        $(Thumbnail).each(function () {
            var CurrentActive = $(Thumbnail).index() + 1; //return current number active thumbnail
            $(this).children('span').append(CurrentActive  + '/' +  AllNumber);
        });
    }

    new ThumbnailCounter();

});
```

```css
.thm-img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumb-wrp scrollbar-inner">
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/a.jpg"><span class="numeric active"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/b.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/c.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/d.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/a.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/c.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/b.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="thm-img">
    <img src="../img/img/d.jpg"><span class="numeric"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your script:

```
function ThumbnailCounter() {
        var AllNumber = $(Thumbnail).length;
        $('.thm-img').each(function () {
            var CurrentActive = $(this).index() + 1; // Use $(this) to reference to current element - it will give you right index
            $(this).children('span').append(CurrentActive  + '/' +  AllNumber);
        });
    }

    new ThumbnailCounter();
```

Comment: LoL I make it with myself :D but thank for helping me :*

Comment: good :) but mark it as correct if you find it useful, so others can get it

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
$(".thumb-wrp .thm-img").each(function() {
  var index = $(".thumb-wrp .thm-img").index(this) + 1;
  var total = $(".thumb-wrp .thm-img").length;
  $(this).find("span").text(index + "/" + total);
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/226/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 var CurrentActive = $(this).index() + 1;
```